# Directory Hierarchy

Tags: java, mongodb

How to build a folder structure using morphia or the mongodb API? I am looking for something like this.

```
folderA
--->folderB
--->folderC
------>fileC
------>folderCA
---------->fileCA
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why do you want a build a folder structure with a database or in a database? Do you want to store files in gridfs? What kind of entities/data do you want to store in MongoDB? Or do you want to store meta information about folders and files in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this type of structure should be really easy to implement.

You basically have two collections `folders` and `files`.

Elements in `folders` have this structure:

```
{ 
  "_id":mongoid,
  "name":"folderA", 
  "properties":"etc",
  ...
  "folders":[{"folderB":refB}, {"folderC":refC}],
  "files":[{"fileA":refA}]
}
```

Elements in `files` are really simple:

```
{
  "_id":mongoid,
  "name":"fileA",
  "size":1234,
  ...
}
```

So basically a folder object is simply an object (with properties) that contains two arrays: one array of "sub-folders" and one array of "files in that folder".

The arrays could just be references, but in this case I've stored it as name and reference. This makes it easier to list at least some file information.